# What is a Verbose Output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, verbose

I am currently using the GridSearchCV object in python. The function call gives an me option to specify the verbosity. Does anyone know what verbose means in this context? I have not found [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to be helpful in this respect. Help on clarifying what this is and what it is used for would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know the specific library but the term itself is used to describe how much debugging info you want your program to give you. A very verbose program might print every single step it does, while low verbosity might only report critical errors

Comment: For reference for anyone else reading this, the relevant documentation is "**verbose : *integer*** Controls the verbosity: the higher, the more messages."

Comment: For the pure-python analogy, you can look at the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) module. You can suppress or enable different events being reported based on the level you specify when you run the code

Answer (score 3):

Verbosity means how much extra info you want the script to give. In your instance, it likely means how much information it should return to you, whether it be the absolute basic query or detailed information about searches; it can also control the amount of results given.

Answer (score 2):

Verbose is just the info you want to be printed when your Gridsearch is running. Just trying to change it (try 2, or 3) you will see for yourself.